# Video capture in openCV 3.1 not working with python3

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.5, opencv3.1

I have installed openCV 3.1.0 with python3.5 every thing seemed to work fine during installation however when I am trying to execute even the following simple program, it doesn't work. OpenCV doesn't detect the camera.

[image: isOpened() function always returning false]

I checked, and the webcam has the id 0, I also tried other values (1,2,-1) but none of them seems to work, it always shows false. I have gone through similar questions on stack overflow, but none of the solutions seems to work. I have also tried re-installing openCV multiple times, it doesn't help either.

Please help.

Comment: is it usb plugged camera?

Comment: no it's the default one, I have also tried usb plugged (with port 0,1,2,-1 and I checked when usb cam is plugged, the default cam is at 0 and usb one is at 1). It doesn't work for either of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should change default camera to video to test.
e.g.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'E:/test.mp4')
if cap.isOpened():
    print('OK')
else:
    print('error')
```

If the result is 'OK',then modify "cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'E:/test.mp4')" to 
"cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)",if the result is 'error',I think there is something wrong with your camera.

Comment: camera is fine, already checked it, such solutions were available in the other questions as well (which i did mention I already tried)